# Marking the end points in graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code-

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[-1,10],[5,12],[7,13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Hops','Frequency'])

plt.figure()
df.plot(x='Hops',y='Frequency',kind='bar',width=0.2,color='blue') 
plt.xlabel('Hops')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.ylim([0,20])
plt.xlim([-10,10])
```

The graph generated is-
[image]

I wanted to mark the limits in the x axis which is -10 to 10.In my code it is showing the markings in the y axis but not in the x axis.

Comment: @Bazingaa I had tried that already it gives the same answer....

Comment: You can manually set the x ticks and labels with `plt.xticks`. Or you can use `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` directly.

Comment: If you're otherwise happy with the bar plot you generated, the limits to use would be `plt.xlim(-1,len(df))`. That is because you have a categorical barplot which goes from `0` to `number of items-1`. Else, you can plot a numeric bar plot with matplotlib's `bar` function.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest tried the limits plt.xlim(-1,len(df)) but it didn't work..

Comment: The result will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLvoL.png). What do you not like about it?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest my question was I wanted to mark the range of my x axis range which is -10,10 in the x axis....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to overwrite the formatting that pandas does by default. You can manually set the x ticks and labels using `plt.xticks`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[-1,10],[5,12],[7,13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Hops','Frequency'])

plt.figure()
df.plot(x='Hops',y='Frequency',kind='bar',width=0.2,color='blue') 
plt.xlabel('Hops')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.ylim([0,20])
plt.xlim([-10,10])
plt.xticks([-10, 0, 10], [-10, 0, 10])  # Or whatever you need them to be
```

Alternatively, you can just use `plt.bar` directly and avoid pandas formatting.

```
plt.bar(df['Hops'], df['Frequency'])
plt.xlabel('Hops')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.ylim([0,20])
plt.xlim([-10,10])
```

Comment: But this removes the x axis labels of the existing columns

Comment: Yes, you have to manually set them. But if you just want the bounds and columns labelled, `plt.xticks([-10, 0, 1, 2, 10], [-10, -1, 5, 7, 10])` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is a bit unclear, one needs to guess here. As far as I interprete it you want to show a numeric bar plot, where bars are at the positions given by their `x` values. pandas bar plots are categorical in nature. So to plot a numeric bar plot you would want to use matplotlib.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[-1,10],[5,12],[7,13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Hops','Frequency'])

plt.figure()
plt.bar(x='Hops',height='Frequency', width=0.2, color='blue', data=df) 
plt.xlabel('Hops')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.ylim([0,20])
plt.xlim([-10,10])

plt.show()
```

[image]